# Add more external space to my ACT Trail 32

Tags: hiking, backpacks

I would like to add a bit more space (any way is acceptable) to my Deuter ACT Trail 32.
http://www.deuter.com/US/us/hiking/act-trail-32-34432-119.html

I do understand it will not be a permament solution but for emergencies or for just walking from point A to B I would like to have this option.

An idea is put carabiners on the red circles below (there is another one on the other side).

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if this vertical grey loop was designed to be significantly loaded. Maybe it's better to hang things into the compression strap, using the loop just as a stopper to prevent movement.

Comment: you are right it was not. but I would put something lighter in the "extension" anyway. i still want heavy stuff near my back.

Answer (score 3):

- Carabiners on the shoulder straps can add two bags of easy-access items. Just don't put more than several kilograms inside, the shoulder straps soft mesh could get damaged.
- Carabiners on the waist strap can comfortably fit sandals or other shoes.

Get the lightest carabiners possible, for example [this](http://www.dx.com/p/outdoor-sports-carabiner-hook-set-silver-black-15-piece-set-143856#.U4RH0ShY4Q0) for bags and something larger, but still light, not climbing gear, for the sandals.

[image]

Comment: that´s kind of one of the things I thought. Actually i thought of connecting a Cordura bag with two carabiners horizontally hanging from the back below the bottom of the pack. i will let you know how it goes on the field!

Comment: I have some experience with hanging my boots that way. Unfortunately, the shoelaces elongate during travel and the boots kick me in the butt on every step! I guess a carefully fastened bag won't have such a problem. I hope you have webbing on the bottom of the pack, to connect the bag to. You can use a rope there, to fasten it firmly and prevent swaying.

Comment: Also, for your next backpack, you might consider one with sleeping pad/tent fasteners at the lower back, like this: http://cdn2-b.examiner.com/sites/default/files/styles/article_large/hash/ec/41/1373610986_4532_IMG_6035.jpg?itok=KgPnM4lZ

Comment: i have that in my large backpack but I do not like things sticking out plus I want to keep it nice and uniform. i attached an image and edited my question.